# rake aborted! LoadError: cannot load such file -- pilosa

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tried rake for one of my team's projects. It throws error as,

```
**rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- pilosa**
```

As the **rake** failed saying gem pilosa was not found, tried installing it. *gem install* also failed and returned result as *valid gem not found*,

```
~  $gem install pilosa
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'pilosa' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: mimosa, nicosa, paloma, pelusa, phl-opa
```

Also when I searched for the gem pilosa both in Local and Remote, it returned empty result as below,

```
~  $gem search pilosa

*** REMOTE GEMS ***


~  $gem search -l pilosa

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
```

Is **pilosa** a valid gem? The project for which I tried rake build, requires pilosa and also uses it methods as below,

```
    require "pilosa"
    ******
    ******
    Pilosa.copyfiles *****
```

Can someone point out the error behind the above problem? Have I done any steps incorrectly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no gem with that name. Is the project using bundler? If so, maybe use `bundle exec rake build`. Though, if you have a team, best to ask them as they have the most knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like either an internal gem or a library created within the project.

To check whether a gem exists or not, search rubygems:
[https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=✓&query=pilosa](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=pilosa)

[image: No such gem as Pilosa]

Also, can you share gem sources? e.g.

```
$gem sources
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

https://rubygems.org/
```